# remove gazebo but keeping the rest of ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed the `ros-fuerte-desktop-full` package. I have never used `ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo`, so I would like to remove it.

However, ros-fuerte-desktop-full depends on it, so if I want to remove gazebo, everything ROS related will get removed. Is there a way (besides installing every package manually) to remove gazebo and keeping the rest of ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46367/remove-gazebo-but-keeping-the-rest-of-ros/) by [Carlito](https://answers.ros.org/users/3262/carlito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-10-20**:
@Carlito Why remove gazebo ? it doesn't occupy too much of space. If you are very particular then consider installing ROS-Comm: (Bare Bones) installation and add packages as per your requirement - http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can remove any ROS component & packages that depend on it with `apt-get`, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo
```

should remove just gazebo related and dependent packages.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3